# Making Dependent Combobox in codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter

i am suffering greatly but still unable to make a dependent dropdown box in Codeigniter .
Here is the schema :

```
groups(group_id,group)
forum(forum_id,subject)
group_forum(group_id,forum_id)
```

Here is my code :
**model**

```
function get_group(){

    $query = $this->db->get('group');
    return $query->result();
}

function get_subject_by_group($id)
{


        $subjects=array();

        $this->db->from('forum');
        $this->db->join('group_forum','group_forum.forum_id=forum.forum_id','group_id='.$id);
        $q=$this->db->get();
       foreach($q->result() as $y)
       {
           $subjects[$y['forum_id']] = $y['subject'];
       }


       return $subjects;

    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
   <?php
class  C_control_form extends  CI_Controller {

     function add_all(){

        #Validate entry form information
        $this->load->model('Model_form');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_group', 'Group', 'trim|required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_forum', 'Forum', 'trim|required');


        $data['groups'] = $this->Model_form->get_group(); //gets the available groups for the dropdown

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {

              $this->load->view('header_for_combo',$data);
              $this->load->view('view_form_all', $data);
              $this->load->view('footer_for_combo',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            #Add Member to Database
            $this->Model_form->add_all();
            $this->load->view('view_form_success');
        }
    }

 function get_subjects($group)
  {
       //echo "hi";
        $this->load->model('Model_form');
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        echo (json_encode($this->Model_form->get_subject_by_group($group)));

    }



}
?>
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"); ?>"  ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // $('#f_group, #f_forum').hide();
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#f_group').change(function(){

            var group_id = $('#f_group').val();
            if (group_id != ""){


              var post_url = "index.php/c_control_form/get_subjects/"+group_id;
              //    var post_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>"+"c_control_form/get_subjects"+group_id;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: post_url,
                    dataType : 'json',

                    success: function(subjects) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
                    {
                        $("#f_forum > option").remove();

                      //  $('#f_forum').empty();
                      //  $('#f_forum, #f_forum_label').show();

                        $.each(subjects,function(forum_id,subject)
                        {
                            var opt = $('<option/>'); // here we're creating a new select option for each group
                            opt.val(forum_id);
                            //alert(id);
                            opt.text(subject);
                            $('#f_forum').append(opt);
                        });
                    } //end success
                }); //end AJAX
            } else {
                $('#f_forum').empty();
            //   $('#f_forum, #f_forum_label').hide();
            }//end if

        }); //end change

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open('c_control_form/add_all'); ?>
    <p>
    <label for="f_group">Group<span class="red">*</span></label>

    <select id="f_group" name="f_group">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        foreach($groups as $group){
            echo '<option value="' . $group->group_id . '">' . $group->group_name.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="f_forum">Subject<span class="red">*</span></label>


    <select id="f_forum" name="f_forum" id="f_forum_label">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    </p>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>  
</body>
```

Comment: What is the response you are getting from the get_subjects method if you type the url in browser with group id? and one suggestion. Can a forum belongs to more than one group? Otherwise can avoid the third table and a column groupid to the forum table.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\uaanew4\application\models\model_form.php:2)

Filename: controllers/c_control_form.php

Line Number: 33                                                                   Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\xampp\htdocs\uaanew4\application\models\model_form.php on line 24 When i am typing url in browser , And yes a forum can belong to more than one group . Thanks @Nish

Comment: Remove all the spaces before and after the php tags in model file and try..

Comment: Now no errors , and window is coming prompting to save or open file

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$subjects[$y['forum_id']] = $y['subject'];
```

to

```
$subjects[$y->forum_id] = $y->subject;
```

in the model file. Also spaces or newlines in model php file after and before the php tags.

**EDIT:** Added below

```
function(subjects){
    var select = $('#f_forum').empty();
    $.each(subjects.values, function(i,item) {
        select.append( '<option value="'
                             + item.id
                             + '">'
                             + item.name
                             + '</option>' ); 
    });
```

Comment: still same the 2nd drop down box is not getting data , even in the view file i gave an alert inside ajax but no response.@Nish

Comment: Before going in to checking the ajax, need to check the response by directly typing the url that is called by AJAX. What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error , rather open file or save file window is prompting @Nish

Comment: comment header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8'); in get_subjects and let me know the output.

Comment: {"1":"physic1","2":"physics1","3":"physic2","4":"physics2","5":"chemistry1","6":"chemistry1","7":"acc1","8":"acc1","9":"acc2","10":"acc2","11":"economics1","12":"economics2","13":"economics2","14":"economics1"}

Comment: Edited my response. Please replace the success ajax function with that.